# Calculating the curvature of high-dimensional data?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

I'm not a mathematician so maybe this question is ill-posed or silly.  Let's say I have a well-behaved function $f : \mathbb{R}^K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$, where $K<N$.  Clearly the outputs of $f$ lie on a $K$-dimensional manifold in $N$-dimensional space, and I can obtain relatively sparse measurements of the function $f$.  Is there a way to measure the curvature of this manifold from data, or at the very least assess the non-planarness of the manifold?

To be a little more concrete, what I really want to assess is the degree to which $\alpha f(k_1) + \beta f(k_2) \neq f(\alpha k_1+\beta k_2)$ for aribtrary points $k_1$ and $k_2$ in the original space.  For these purposes, is curvature even an appropriate measure or is there something better? A global measure of this property would be ideal.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to call this *nonlinearity* rather than curvature. It would be difficult to define a good measure of nonlinearity without more information about the function $f$. E.g. Is $f(0)=0$? Is $f$ differentiable? How many times?

Comment: What you are after is the [second fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form) and the calculations obtainable from it. The wikipedia article is only about 3D, but the concept generalizes to any number of dimensions. The second fundamental form is about the relationship of a submanifold with its ambient space, while the first fundamental form is intrinsic to the submanifold itself.